# Variable might not have been initialized when dealing with array

Tags: java

In a method I created I am trying to create is meant to return an array of user inputted strings.  The issue that I am having it the compiler is saying that `userData` may not be initialized at `userData[i]=tempData;` and at `return userData;`. I am unsure why this error is occuring, and would like some feedback.

```
public String[] getStringObj() {
    int i = 0;
    String tempData;
    String[] userData;
    Boolean exitLoop = false;
    System.out.println("Please list your values below, separating each item using the return key.  To exit the input process please type in ! as your item.");
    do {
        tempData = IO.readString();
        if (tempData.equals("!")) {
            exitLoop=true;
        } else {
            userData[i] = tempData;
            i++;
        }
    } while (exitLoop == false);
    return userData;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable might not have been initialized error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error)

Comment: compiler is correct this time. _variable is not initialized_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interests of improving code quality:

1. You don't need that `exitLoop` flag; just do

   ```
   while(true) {
       String input = IO.readString();
       if(input.equals("!")) {
           break;
       }
       /* rest of code */
   }
   ```
2. Since you seem like you want to just add stuff to an array without bounds, use an `ArrayList` instead of an array (added bonus, this gets rid of `i` too):

   ```
   List<String> userData = new ArrayList<String>();
   ...
   userData.add(line);
   ```

If you do these two things, your code will be much more concise and easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Your `userData` is not initilaized and you are attempting to use it here `userData[i]=tempData;` before initialization.

Initialize it as

```
String[] userData = new String[20]; 

//20 is the size of array that I specified, you can specify yours
```

Also in your `while` condition you can have `while(!exitLoop)` instead of `while(exitLoop==false)`

Comment: I do not want a limit as to how many String values the user can input.  Is there a way I can put in an arbitrarily large number for the length and then re-size to remove the tailing null values?

Comment: For that you better use `ArrayList`- As elements are added to an `ArrayList`, its capacity grows automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize the `String[]`. Just do `String[] userData = new String[length]`. If you are unsure of the length, you may just want to use an `ArrayList<String>`.