# instantiated object's method won't run, error "variable(object's name) not initialized

Tags: java, object, instantiation

/** There seems to be a problem with the intended method call from the performance class. The object is recognized as band but for some reason when i call band.begin() (band is the new performance object and begin its method) band is not recognized and it suggests it be initialized as a variable? */

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Music {

public static Instrument assignInstrument () {
    String instrumentChoice;
    String name;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


    System.out.println("Select an instrument for the band member. ");
    System.out.print("Vocals, piccolo, Clarinet, Cymbal, or Drum: ");
    instrumentChoice = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the band member's name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    if (instrumentChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("v")) {
        return (new Vocal(name));
    }   else if (instrumentChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
        return (new Piccolo(name));
    }   else if (instrumentChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("cl")) {
        return (new Clarinet(name));
    }   else if (instrumentChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("cy")) {
        return (new Cymbal(name));
    }   else {
        return (new Drum(name));
    }
  }

/** I instantiated a "band" performance object but it is not recognizing it when i call its method... */
  public static void main (String [] args){
    Performance band; // band object instantiated
    Instrument bandmember1, bandmember2, bandmember3, bandmember4;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String performanceChoice;

    bandmember1 = assignInstrument();
    bandmember2 = assignInstrument();
    bandmember3 = assignInstrument();
    bandmember4 = assignInstrument();
    System.out.println(bandmember1 + " " + bandmember2 + " " + bandmember3 + " " +     bandmember4 + "\n");

    System.out.print("Would you like to hear a solo, duet, trio, quartet, or leave?:  ");
    performanceChoice = input.nextLine();
    while (!performanceChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) { // choosing the correct form of object
        if (performanceChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
            band = new Performance (bandmember1);
        }   else if ( performanceChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
            band = new Performance (bandmember1, bandmember2);
        }   else if ( performanceChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            band = new Performance (bandmember1, bandmember2, bandmember3);
        }   else {
            band = new Performance (bandmember1, bandmember2, bandmember3, bandmember4);
        }
    }
            band.Begin(); // error message: "variable band might not have been initialized".? 
 }
}


public class Performance {
private String arrangement;
private Instrument solo;
private Instrument duet_1, duet_2;
private Instrument trio_1, trio_2, trio_3;
private Instrument quart_1, quart_2, quart_3, quart_4;






public Performance (Instrument s) {
    solo = s;
    arrangement = solo.makeSound();
}

public Performance (Instrument d1, Instrument d2){
    duet_1 = d1;
    duet_2 = d2;
    arrangement = duet_1.makeSound() + duet_2.makeSound();
}

public Performance (Instrument t1, Instrument t2, Instrument t3){
    trio_1 = t1;
    trio_2 = t2;
    trio_3 = t3;
    arrangement = trio_1.makeSound() + trio_2.makeSound() + trio_3.makeSound();
}

public Performance (Instrument q1, Instrument q2, Instrument q3, Instrument q4){
    quart_1 = q1;
    quart_2 = q2;
    quart_3 = q3;
    quart_4 = q4;
    arrangement = quart_1.makeSound() + quart_2.makeSound() + quart_3.makeSound() + quart_4.makeSound();
}

public void Begin() {
    System.out.print(arrangement);
}

public String toString(){
    String program = "The performance includes ";
    program += arrangement;
    return program;
}
}
   /** Any suggestions? Thanks in advance*/
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an error and not a warning? Your `while` loop is not guaranteed to run at least once.  And if it runs it would never stop, since you do not update `performanceChoice` in it.

Comment: yea thats what i thought too so i was like screw it ill run it anyway but it was actually an error (63, 17)

Comment: even if i change it to do that doesn't change its unrecognition as an object or method. it seems simple enough though. i even tried changing each band = new Performance""... to Performance band = new Performance"" but no avail :(

Comment: duplicate of [variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
Performance band;
```

To:

```
Performance band = null;
```

This happens, since the compiler isn't sure the variable is ever assigned a value (if the while won't pass in first place). Although you could work with null values (resulting in NPEs in some cases), you can't work with unassigned values.

Recall, a global variable is automatically assigned to null, but not local variables.

Note this is true even if logically it must be assigned, for example in a `try-catch` block, you'll have to initialize *and define* ( probably `null`) before the `try`, in order to use it, since the compiler is not sure it will ever be assigned in the `try`, but rather catch an exception. Even if you call `System.exit(1)` in the `catch` block. That means, logically it must be defined (otherwise the program will terminate) but the compiler is not *so* smart ;)

Comment: i copied it from a text book thats suppose to teach the right to way to program. Guess its not that great.