# Java variable might not have been initialized. But it should be

Tags: java

I'm using a variable `line`, which after the method turns into `lineOld`. So for the first time running the method `lineOld` is undefined.

So while compiling it gives me the error variable `lineOld` might not have been initialized.

I've tried to give `lineOld` a value just once (See first `for` and `while`), but no go.

Any help :) ?

```
String inputLine;
String lineOld;
String line = "";
int test = 0;

for (int i = 0; i == 0; i++) {
    lineOld = "";
}

while (test == 0) {
    lineOld = "";
    test++;
}

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line + inputLine;
}

System.out.println(line);

if (line == lineOld) {
    System.out.println("No difference");
} else {
    System.out.println("VERSCHIL");
}

lineOld = line;
```

Comment: Why can't you just initialize them like `line`? Also: [compare strings with `.equals()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Ps: that `lineOld` initializer is.. rather ugly.

Comment: Because this method keeps repeating, so I dont want lineOld to be reset every time.

Comment: lineOld can't hold its value between calls unless it's a global variable.

Comment: Even if that was a good approach, it would still not be a good idea because it will still reset your `lineOld` every time the method is called. I suggest that, once you get your code fixed and working, you visit [CodeReview.se](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) so we can provide you with a more indepth explanation on how your program *should* work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable might not have been initialized error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error)

Answer (score 3):

Simply initialize `lineOld` to some dummy variable, either `""` or `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is pointing it out because there is a possibility that the for/while blocks do not execute, which would mean that lineOld is not initialized. It's looking for you to initialize it outside of a block.

Answer (score 1):

On initialisation set lineOld to null

```
String lineOld = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem here, is that (as far as the compiler can see) it is possible for for this code to follow a path that will result in `lineOld` not being initialized prior to its use.

To fix this, you will need to initialize it outside of a conditional construct.

```
String lineOld = "";
```

"Because this method keeps repeating, so I dont want lineOld to be reset every time."

In that case, pass lineOld to this method.  Check if the passed-in lineOld has a value, and initialize the local lineOld to it.  If the passed-in lineOld does not have a value, then initialize the local lineOld to either a null or empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler giving correct error because 
at this line,
`if(line == lineOld){`
there might be a possibility that above for/while blocks do not execute, which means that lineOld is not initialized.

You can remove this error by initializing it to some dummy variable "" or null.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use while or for controle to initialize your variable ? you can use if :

```
 if(test == 0){
    lineOld = "";
    test++;
}
```

but the better way I think is to initialize lineOld at null or "" then use this test :

```
 if(line.equals(lineOld))
```