# Are uninitialized variables set to null by default in Java?

Tags: java, null, initialization

I thought that an uninitialized variables are set to null by default example shown below:

```
Public class foo{
Object bar;

    public void check(){
       while(bar != null){
          // Do something

        }
      }
    }
```

Inside the method I am getting an error about checking an uninitialized object. But by default Java would set this to null?
Thanks

Comment: if you declare your object and don't instantiate than it will by default set to null.

Comment: @The3211 No. Not it will not. That generalisation is incorrect.

Comment: @BoristheSpider hey but if we try to access that element than it will give you nullPointerException right?

Comment: @The3211 it depends. It might not compile, depending on _where_ you "declare your object". Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Object bar should have been initialised to null.
You might get a warning about using an uninitialised variable.