# Why do I get "The local variable may not have been initialized" error?

Tags: java

```
package io;

import java.io.*;

public class UserIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        char c;
        try {
            c = (char)br.read(); //Input a character from user
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("c: " + c);
    }
}
```

The program is unable to compile.

> Error: The local variable c may not have been initialized

Comment: So initialize it - `Char c = NULL;`

Comment: You're literally telling us the reason: The local variable c may not have been initialized. Initialize it. Otherwise the println() won't have a value to use in case the try block fails.

Comment: @TDG, in Java, it's not `NULL`, it's `null`.

Comment: ^ and you cannot assign null to primitive types...

Comment: Hint: the compiler sees that when you get an exception while reading the input, variable `c` would remain unassigned. You need assign it in the `catch`, assign it unconditionally, or not use `c` outside the `try` block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable might not have been initialized error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intialize `char c = '';`.

If your `try` block fails your character `c` will not have any value.

```
  try {
    c = (char)br.read(); //Input a character from user
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

The above code might not assign any value to `c`, if there is some `Exception` thrown within `br.read()`. So when to execute `System.out.println("c: " + c);`, the compiler does not know what to print. In order to avoid this, Java forces you to initialize local variables.

If you intialize `c` with `char c = '';`, even though your `try` block fails, the compiler can at least print ``.

**You should be able to do something like :**

```
 char c;
 c = 'a';
 System.out.println("c:" + c);
```

In this case it will compile successfully, because when you print the value compiler knows it will certainly have some value, which is not the case with your `try` block (it might or might not have any value).

Comment: working fine after char c = ' ' ; but why was try failing earlier?

Comment: @ArpitTomar I added some explanation to the answer. Let me know if you have doubt in that.

Comment: understood now, appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it: In case the `try` block fails, what will be printed out by `System.out.println("c: " + c)`? Well, whatever value `c` had before the `try`-block. What value did `c` last hold before the try block? Nothing, you didn't specify any prior value, the value is not initialized. Hence, the error message.

Solution: Give `c` a default value upon declaration (or in a `finally` block). One that can be used in case the try-block fails.

Comment: You might want to mention that this effect is due to the fact, that `c` is a local variable. If `c` were a field of an object, it would have a defaulf value since `char` is a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually read what the user is inputting after they have finish

```
        while ((c = (char) br.read()) != -1) {
               System.out.println("c: " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of simply posting code, please explain the problem OP had and the solution. *Give a man a fish, and he has food for a day. Teach a man to fish and he will never be hungry again*.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know you still need this solution, but i wanna answer your ask.
after catch exception, you could use "return;" to back, and in order to not break "c".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    char c;
    try {
        c = (char)br.read(); //Input a character from user
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
`       return;
    }
    System.out.println("c: " + c);
}
```