# Why Boolean variable is not initialized by default in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I switched from eclipse to android studio recently. During coding i got some strange behavior. I am having boolean variable where i am passing to if condition like this.

```
boolean permissionGranted;
if(permissionGranted){
//Do work
}else{
}
```

It works fine with eclipse. But in android studio it ask me to initialize boolean variable;
[image: Error for boolean variable]

As per my understanding by default boolean varaible will be intialized to false. Still studio asking me to intialize by myself. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: is your boolean a class member? or is it declared inside a method?

Comment: Studio is very good to show warnings, have you checked in eclipse by running the application it might thought error while compilation. Simple solution initialize the variables .

Comment: It's declared inside method; Just try in studio.

Comment: Its not Android Studio problem and responsibility to initialize the variable, Not at all IDE side its all about java.

Comment: as far as i remember, method variables are not initialized automatically, only class fields get initialized to their respective default values

Comment: Eclipse should complain about that, too. Either way, it is an error, won't compile and you have to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable might not have been initialized error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error)