# My variable is not initialized?

Tags: java

I have this method.

The error says

> primeList might not have been initialized.

I can't understand how this can be true. I feel like there's no way the variable wouldn't be initialized out of the for loops.

I can't figure out how to initialize a String

```
public void primesToANumber(long num) //finds all primes
{
    String primeList ;
    long pcount;
    long limit = num;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Prime numbers between 1 and " + limit);
    for(long i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for(long j = 2; j < i ; j++)
        {
         if(i % j == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // print the number
        if(isPrime)
        {
            primeList += i + ", ";
            pcount++;
            if(pcount % 12 ==0){
                primeList += "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " " + primeList);
}
```

Comment: `String primeList =;` shouldn't even compile

Comment: You can't use `+=` on a variable that hasn't been initialised. What are you adding on to?

Comment: What makes you think that variable is/would be initialized?

Comment: What is with all the downvoting? This is a pretty good question for a new user!

Comment: @Pshemo  Well i only started coding about a month ago so I'm just lost on how to initialize this variable. I thought if i defined it outside the outside loop then it would work but apparently not.

Comment: @musefan Because it is basic Java... any tutorial would have covered this. Surprised they got this far

Comment: You will have an issue with `pcount` as well. Try `long pcount = 0L;`

Comment: @Jonk I fixed that. i was working on it in between and copy and pasted the bad version in. It's fixed now

Comment: @AndrewLi: It doesn't matter how *basic* it is. As long as the question meets the asking criteria (which it does). With your logic you might as well down vote all questions and say `"this is advanced Java... any masters degree would have covered this."`

Comment: @musefan Sure, but a simple search on google or *this site* would reveal dupes like this which solve the problem... http://stackoverflow.com/q/2448843/5647260 - the downvote tooltip says "does not show research"

Comment: @AndrewLi: Well then perhaps you should find one that relates to strings and then vote to close this as a dupe

Comment: @musefan I've already found a duplicate...

Comment: @AndrewLi: Well I hope you have downvoted that 'basic' question too...

Comment: @AndrewLi I did research and explore similar questions but I couldn't figure out how it related to mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialise your variable, exactly like it says...

```
String primeList = "";
```

Using an empty string will then allow your code to append to it as you intend, to get your desired result.

---

Just for reference, if you *did* want to use `null` for some reason, you can 'convince' the compiler you know what you are doing by specifying it directly:

```
String primeList = null;
```

This would compile fine, but you would get a runtime error when you try to append to a null String, so it wouldn't make sense to do this in this instance.

Comment: Thanks, that compiled and ran correctly

Comment: @NikitaKovinskiy If this solved answered your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
String primeList = "";
long pcount = 0;
```

and I guess it should be:

```
for (long i = 1; i < limit; i++)
```

insted of

```
for (long i = 1; i < 100; i++)
```