# Variable objectPO might not have been initialized

Tags: java, initialization, instance

I have

```
     PurchaseOrder objectPO = new PurchaseOrder(objectPO.getDateOfOrder(), 
                            "CGL-1234" ,objectPO.getProductType(), 250, 5);
 objectPO.toString();
```

But I get error that objectPO might not have been initialized

[PurchaseOrder class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTJij.jpg)

I have looked through similar posts but couldnt find solution regarding my error. How can I initialize objPO?

Comment: You're using `objectPO` as an argument to initialize `objectPO`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable might not have been initialized error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error)

Comment: @RomaKhomyshyn I think this is different (at least for that link) because he initialized the variable, but he just did it wrong (i.e. using variable to declare itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you can't invoke `objectPO.getDateOfOrder()` and `objectPO.getProductType()` methods before even `objectPO` object is created i.e., you are trying to create `objectPO` object by using the `objectPO` itself (which is part of your `PurchaseOrder` constructor call).

Rather, first create the objects for `OrderDate` (like `orderDateObj`) and `Product` (like `productObj`) by using the constructors of those classes first as shown below and then pass those objects to create `PurchaseOrder` object.

```
OrderDate orderDateObj = new OrderDate(...);//create object for OrderDate
Product productObj = new Product(...);//create object for Product
PurchaseOrder objectPO = new PurchaseOrder(orderDateObj, 
                            "CGL-1234" , productObj, 250, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you, that made perfect sense.