# Assigning variables in try/catch statements?

Tags: java, variables, try-catch

I'm using a try/catch statement to force valid user input to assign to a variable. However, when I try to use this variable outside the try/catch statement, it tells me that my variable has not been initialized. Using Java...
[Link to picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfKJp.png)

```
public static int getChoice() 
{
    //Variables
    int choice;

    do {

        try {
        System.out.println("Press 1 then [Enter] for imperial measurements: ");
        System.out.println("Press 2 then [Enter] for metric measurements: ");
        choice=console.nextInt();
        }

        catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) { //Force valid input of integer

            System.err.println("\nInvalid entry.");
            System.out.println("Press 1 then [Enter] for imperial measurements: ");
            System.out.println("Press 2 then [Enter] for metric measurements: ");
            console.nextLine(); //Flush line buffer
        }


    } while (choice<1||choice>2); //Forces input of either 1 or 2

    return choice;
}
```

Comment: Which language are you using? Add the language name with a tag please.

Comment: `it tells me that my variable has not been initialized` Why not include the actual error message. This will make it much easier to find the duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable might not have been initialized error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error)

Comment: Because it indeed may not be initialized (if it throws a `InputMismatchException`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

The cause of this error is obvious. There is a branch in your code where you could call `choice` without assigning any value to it. This happens when the `try` block is aborted before something is assigned to `choice`.

In this case this would be when an `InputMismatchException` occurs, the `try` block is then aborted and the control flow continues with the `catch` block. After the `catch` block `choice` is accessed though it was not initialized.

```
int choice; // Declaration without initialization
do {
    try {
        // ...
        choice = console.nextInt(); // Exception could be thrown
    } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
        // ...
        // Code then continues here, without choice being initialized
    }
} while (choice < 1 || choice > 2); // Access of unassigned variable
```

---

### Solutions

You have several options for fixing this. You must make sure that there can not be a branch that accesses `choice` unassigned. Therefore, you could assign it with a default value before entering the loop:

```
int choice = -1; // Default value
```

Of course you would need to handle this special case then.

Another possibility is to assign it in the catch block too

```
} catch ( ... ) {
    choice = -1; // Some value indicating an error
}
```

You could make sure that a dangerous branch never reaches `choice`, for example by aborting the code in some way:

```
} catch ( ... ) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(); // Abort by throwing a non-catched exception
}
```

You could protect the access to `choice` with some kind of guard variable:

```
boolean wasError = false;
int choice;
do {
    try {
        // ...
    } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
        // ...
        wasError = true; // Set the guard
    }

    // Check the guard
    if (wasError) {
        // Something went wrong, abort the loop
        break;
    }
} while (choice < 1 || choice > 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either define a value when you declare `choice`, like using `int choice = 0;`, or add a line inside the `catch` clause, `choice = 0;`.