# Is it possible to use a String if statement to change an integer?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I'm just having a practise at some java coding and was wondering if there was a way to use a String if else statement to change change an integer, as the following doesn't like the c = a * b

```
    int a, b, c;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter first number");
    a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter * + - or / ");
    String d = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter second number");
    b = sc.nextInt();
    
    if (d.equals("*")){
        c = a * b;
            
    }
    System.out.println(a + " " + d + " b " + " = " + c);
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable might not have been initialized error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error)

Comment: What is `d` before entering the `if` statement?  Add a debug-print like `System.out.println(d)` before `if` and update your question with its output. Also: add a debug-print inside the `if` block to get notified on console when if-block was entered.

Comment: What does "the following doesn't like" mean? I have never seen such an error message. I highly suggest you add the real error message if you get an error, or an example with expected and actual values if the result is not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the variable "c" is initialized only if the conditional `if (d.equals("*")) {...}` is true, to solve this you have two options:

Just initialize "c" :

```
        int a, b, c = 0;
```

or add else statement

```
        if (d.equals("*")){
            c = a * b;
        }else {
            c = 0;
        }
```

Comment: ️ Important advice here: The `else` branch makes each `if` statement _complete_ (and thus less error-prone) because each paths are covered.

Comment: The java compiler checks all possible path to see if local variables are initialized or not. in your code snipped only place c is getting initialized is if statement. it does not find any other path where c is getting initialized .hence it generates a compile time error