# Local variable may have not been initialized in switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I've initialized the variable I wanted, but after adding it's values through a switch case, I cannot return it. Is there any solutions?`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Masukkan nilai a = ");
        int a = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Masukkan nilai b = ");
        int b = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Mau diapain bang angkanya? ");
        String o = input.next();

        int hasil;
        switch (o) {
        case "+":
            hasil = a + b;
            break;
        case "-":
            hasil = a - b;
            break;
        case "*":
            hasil = a * b;
            break;
        case "/":
            hasil = a / b;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Operator tidak valid");
        }

// Error is here, stating that I haven't initialized the variable
        System.out.println(hasil);

    }
}
```

`

I've tried putting the console out in each of the case, and it did worked. So, is my first way of doing it is not working?

Comment: Assign it a default value when you declare it, or give it one in the default branch. The issue is that it might not be initialized if none of those cases trigger.

Answer (score 1):

It shows that error because you declared them but didn't initialized them.

Your variable should be initialized as `int hasil = 0;`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448843/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error) reference for a better idea. This user has explained it very smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

init your `int hasil = 0;` or assign a value for it in the `default` case

```
default:
  hasil = 0;
  System.out.println("Operator tidak valid");
```